# Log Parser for linux

Tags: linux, logging, logparser

[Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=890cd06b-abf8-4c25-91b2-f8d975cf8c07&displaylang=en) is great tool for parsing log files. I can parse not just IIS log files but also custom log files with it.

[For example](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692659.aspx) I can use SQL syntax to parse logs:

```
C:\>LogParser "SELECT TimeGenerated, SourceName, 
EventCategoryName, Message INTO report.txt FROM Security WHERE 
EventID = 528 AND SID LIKE '%TESTUSER%'" -resolveSIDs:ON
```

Is there any tool like that for linux?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[lnav](http://tstack.github.com/lnav/) supports SQL queries and supports most of the common Linux log formats. Look at the project's [website](http://tstack.github.com/lnav/) and [documentation page](https://lnav.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) for more details and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you'll take a look at [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/)?

When it comes to text based logs `grep` is your friend—it can do pretty much the same what SQL-like syntax in your example.

Answer (score -2):

have you tired tail command ?

```
tail -f /path/to/log/file/log
```

if you prefer a log viewer with GUI, Have a look at
[Gnome Log Viewer](http://library.gnome.org/users/gnome-system-log/)

Comment: I want to parse log files not just read. When I use Log Parser I can parse with SQL like syntax.

Comment: If you like "SQL-like syntax", you could store your logs in SQL.  Rsyslog supports this with great flexibility. And I believe there are some web-based frontends designed to go along with SQL-stored rsyslog databases.  Although it has enough flexibility that you can store your logs in whatever format you like--something I use all the time.

Comment: I have down voted answer because it quite opposite to what was an original question.